# How can an old, committed transaction affect ongoing txns?

Tags: postgresql, isolation-level, transaction-isolation

SQL gurus!

My postgres 15 database is running under the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level and I'm occasionally seeing `serialization_failure (40001)` errors with an odd error message:

```
DETAIL: Reason code: Canceled on identification as a pivot, with conflict out to old committed transaction 39594340.
```

We have limited automated retries for this class of error but in a recent case, nothing could touch the affected tables for over an hour -- any `UPDATE` attempt would fail with the same error.

What's odd to me is that the error cites txn `39594340`, which successfully committed more than 15 minutes before the error messages started showing up in our logs.

This particular variant of error doesn't yield much on Google. Perhaps the most relevant is https://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@lists.postgresql.org/msg156458.html which talks about how predicate locks that run out of shared memory (or txns that hit the `max_pred_locks_per_transaction` limit) can lose a LOT of granularity, particularly if they swap to disk (even the DB can be lost!?!?)

---

Anywho in our case, it seems we have a very complex, long-running txn (call it `txnA`) that is almost certainly hitting the default `max_pred_locks_per_transaction=64` limit. Then we have these other much simpler txns that are basically just executing 1-2 `UPDATE` statements (`txnB`).

Both the committed txn (`old committed transaction 39594340`) and the failing-with-serialization-error txn are of the simple `txnB` type, but may be happening concurrently with `txnA`. Meanwhile, `txnA` isn't touching the same tables as `txnB`, but started before both and was running still when we started to see errors.

It seems maybe there's some tangled web of dependencies, related to loss of specificity in the long-running txn's predicate locks. Is that hypothesis crazy?

How else could a *committed* txn affect a current txn?

TIA for any insights here!

Comment: I suspect that there was a long running transaction somewhere that started before the transaction committed 15 minutes ago. It could be a read-only transaction.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I think that's plausible given my current setup. Are there more details on how that long-running txn could cause the cited (short, committed 15 min) txn to interfere with more recent transactions? Is my hypothesis that the long-running txn's predicate locks are losing specificity even possible, given it's not touching the same tables?

Comment: The SI locks are kept around until the last transaction concurrent with the transaction that caused the lock is gone.

Comment: Ah! @LaurenzAlbe that would certainly explain what I'm seeing. Thanks for the insight. This answers my issue-- feel free to make your comment a proper response and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say what exactly happened, but the predicate locks taken on the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level are kept around until the last concurrent transaction is gone. So there must have been a long-running transaction involved.